# Unknown key in field XXX when using simpl-schema

Tags: meteor, simple-schema

I was using only `aldeed:simple-schema` in my Project with the packages `check` and `audit-argument-checks`.
**The check function using my SimpleSchema was working fine**.

But then i wanted to use collection2.
Collection2 need the npm package `simpl-schema`.
When i installed `aldeed:collection2` and the npm package `simpl-schema`, my checks using SimpleSchema stopped working and now show the following error:

> Error: Match error: Unknown key in field title

Check() is working with `aldeed:simple-schema` but not with the npm package `simpl-schema`.

```
import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';

NoteUpsertSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    max: 50
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    max: 500
  }
});
```

My Meteor Method

```
updateNote(noteId, note){
    check(noteId, String);
    check(note, NoteUpsertSchema);
    // some code
}
```

Versions of my packages:

```
// Meteor packages
aldeed:collection2         3.0.0  
audit-argument-checks      1.0.7 
check                      1.3.0* 

// Npm package
"simpl-schema": "^1.5.0"
(I tried with simpl-schema: 1.4.3 same result.)
```

How can i use the four packages `check`, `audit-argument-checks`, `simple-schema` and `collection2` together ?

Thanks for your answer

Comment: Please always provide the versions of the packages. In case of `simple-schema` there is for example currently a compatibility issue with AutoForm and versions `>=1.5.0` so maybe yours is also related to a recent version update. Please therefore check against version `1.4.3` and see the issue list on github if similar errors have been reported.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'm not home so i will provide the versions later in the day. I'm not using Autoform and i guess i have the last version of simple-schema. Will edit my post as soon as i have the info.

Comment: Well with AutoForm was just an example but there were so many errors reported lately related to `simpl-schema` that my guts feel that there is a general issue with the `simpl-schema` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `NoteUpsertSchema` in `check` utility in Meteor.

`check`, `audit-argument-checks`, `simpl-schema` and `collection2` works very well in synch, there is no such issue with inter-compatibility. `Check` only allows there defined parameters against which you can crosscheck the validity. 
[Click here](https://docs.meteor.com/api/check.html#matchpatterns) to know the details of `check` allowed types.

Considering `audit-argument-checks`, you need to use approach shown as an example below to check arguments passed in Meteor Method. To avoid errors about not checking all arguments when you are using SimpleSchema to validate Meteor method arguments, you must pass check as an option when creating your SimpleSchema instance.

```
import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';
import { check } from 'meteor/check';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

SimpleSchema.defineValidationErrorTransform(error => {
  const ddpError = new Meteor.Error(error.message);
  ddpError.error = 'validation-error';
  ddpError.details = error.details;
  return ddpError;
});

const myMethodObjArgSchema = new SimpleSchema({ name: String }, { check });

Meteor.methods({
  myMethod(obj) {
    myMethodObjArgSchema.validate(obj);

    // Now do other method stuff knowing that obj satisfies the schema
  },
});
```

Make sure the `aldeed:simple-schema` is not listed in `.meteor/versions` file.

Also Problem can be sending a full object from client and only validating some of its fields within meteor method. Make sure the parameter being sent to the method only have what is being validated and no extra field from the client code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i did try using the validate() method but this didn't satisfy `audit-argument-checks`: `Error: Did not check() all arguments`. Maybe i imported meteor/check the wrong way, i will check this evening and i will edit my post to add this code.

Comment: We have to check all arguments that are passed to the Meteor method call.

Comment: Ok i was importing 'check' the wrong way. I did `import check from 'meteor/check';` Instead of `import { check } from 'meteor/check';`. Your solution solved my problem.